# FOUT with the @Font-your-face module and fonts.com causing Screen Flash

Tags: 7, theming

I am working on a site with fonts provided by fonts.com

We had an issue of FOUT(flash of unstyled text), which we managed to correct by using the following from fonts.com

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// first, create the object that contains
// configuration variables
MTIConfig = {};
// next, add a variable that will control
// whether or not FOUT will be prevented
MTIConfig.EnableCustomFOUTHandler = true // true = prevent FOUT
</script>
```

However it is creating a seperate issue that on every page load the screen flashes white.

I have searched for documentation regarding this class on fonts.com but cannot find how to alter which tag it chooses.

I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem and how you solved it.

Comment: I have found some issues with web-fonts in Drupal as well a site I've worked on. What happens when you turn on CSS/JS aggregation? Any change?

Comment: CSS + JS aggregation doesnt appear to affect this issue, i had them turned on when the issue was raised. I have since turn them off  while I looking for the cause. and the issue is still in place